# Circuit representation of internal capacitor resistance

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, capacitance, dielectric

In the circuit representation of a capacitor, why is the internal resistance of the capacitor, caused by the dielectric medium between its plates, taken to be parallel to it?

Answer (score 0):

An ideal capacitor does not allow DC current to flow at all. In real capacitors, the dielectric material separating conductive plates does not provide perfect insulation, and allows current to leak through it, though typically very little. This is referred to as the "DC leakage current".

If we modeled this circuit as an ideal capacitor with a resistor in series, no current would flow still because the ideal capacitor looks like an open circuit at DC. A very large parallel resistor accounts for leakage current.